# Facebook Graph API method /{user-id}/likes returns empty data, although user_likes permission is used for user access_token

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to use Facebook Graph API. When I request method */{user-id}/likes* it returns data only for access_token owner, but for other users it returns empty data (even if users' likes are public). I use user access_token with **user_likes** permission. API version **2.10**.

Is it right behavior or bug in Facebook Graph API?

Comment: why would you want to get the likes of other users? of course they have to authorize your app too, with the user_likes permission. it does not matter if something is public or not.

Comment: @luschn Thanks! I just want to pick some public stats about facebook users.

Comment: that´s impossible. ANY data you want to get requires explicit permission/authorization of the specific user. again, it does not matter if something is public on facebook.com.